# Random distinct numbers in nested loop

Tags: java, for-loop, random, nested-loops

I am have enrolled in java course and completed nested loops but I was trying to play around with it and wanted to make columns of distinct random numbers but it prints 1 number to all columns. How can I make it so it prints random number to every slot (numbers can be repeated but not copied like its now)

```
    Random rng = new Random();
    int chance = rng.nextInt((100)+1);
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row ++) {
        System.out.print("row " + row + ": ");
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
            System.out.print(chance + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This is the result:

row 0: 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13

row 1: 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13

row 2: 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13

row 3: 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13

row 4: 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13

but what I need is every number to be randomly generated and not just roll 1 number and put it everywhere.

Comment: Try computing `chance` _inside_ the loop .

Comment: Move the assign of the chance variable inside the nested for loop.

Comment: So it was quite simple solution, thank you! works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
int chance = rng.nextInt((100)+1);
```

That line gets you a new random number and assigns it to your local variable.

Your code executes the above statement **once**, prior to the for loop. And then your loop prints what you put into that local variable.

If you want it to happen that "get me a random number" repeatedly, consider moving it **into** your loop.

That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this .
Placing the chance variable inside the loop will provide a new random number each time.

```
        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row ++) {
            System.out.print("row " + row + ": ");
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                int chance = rng.nextInt((100)+1);
                System.out.print(chance + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```